# How can I add only subset of modules inside *.d.ts file in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Currently we have a TypeScript project and after each build a *.d.ts file is auto generated and it contains all of the types and modules we use in the project. 
We want to add only public API to the *.d.ts file not all of the types and modules.
Is there any way to achieve that in auto generation manner?

**UPDATE**: So guys, after some research I found an option to Typescript compiler '**--stripInternal**' (Do not emit declarations for code that has an /** @internal */ JSDoc annotation.) which basically do the job.

Here is the original link: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Compiler%20Options.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably run `tsc --declaration *files*` in your project. That makes the the `*.d.ts files`.

You can split your files to those who contain only public APIs, and the rest of them. Then, you can run `tsc --declaration` only on the public APIs files.

Comment: Thanks! We will try that for sure.